# How to access $.ajax success variables outside scope to use in othe functions?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Before posting this I've read through but I'm still not clear on how to achieve this.
I'm receiving an xml file and setting some variable, how can I access all of the variables outside the ajax success to use in other functions?

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: getProductList,
    data: reqProductXML,
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success: function (data) {
        $(xml).find('product').each(function () {
            var productID = $(this).find('id').text();
            var productName = $(this).find('name').text();
            var productCurrency = $(this).find('currency').text();
            var productDescription = $(this).find('description');
            var sipAccess = $(this).find('sipAccess');
            var skypeAccess = $(this).find('skypeAccess');
            var localAccess = $(this).find('localAccess');
            var rechargeable = $(this).find('rechargeable').text();

           $('#urProductSelect').append("<option value='" + productID + "'>" + productName + "</option>");
        });
    }
}); //End ajax

    // I need to use the variable out here....
   $('#urProductSelect').change(function () {...});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of the scope where the variables were defined, because you are defining your variables within the ajax `success` function all the variables belong to that scope, so any other function defined outside that function won't be able to "see" that variables, you can define them outside the `success` function within a scope that any other function will be able to "see" them like the global scope but that is kind of messy. Take a look at this book, It will show you some good examples about scope and closures too:

http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#example-2.44

Answer (score 2):

Define variables at a place such that they are in scope of both the functions,
such as

```
var productID;
```

Inside $.ajax use them as

```
productID = $(this).find('id').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think better to create callback function:

```
$.post(site_url+"admin/jx_get_group_attibutes", {product_id:id}, function(rdata) {

            if(rdata.status == 'success') {
                print_link_products(rdata); // callback function
            }
            else {
                alert(rdata.result);
                return false;
            }
        }, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change for example `var productID` to `window.productID` to make it global. Remember to take care when using global variables as naming issues can come into play.

Answer (score 0):

```
var productID, productName, productCurrency, productDescription, sipAccess, skypeAccess, localAccess, rechargeable;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: getProductList,
    data: reqProductXML,
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success: function (data) {
        $(xml).find('product').each(function () {
            productID = $(this).find('id').text();
            productName = $(this).find('name').text();
            productCurrency = $(this).find('currency').text();
            productDescription = $(this).find('description');
            sipAccess = $(this).find('sipAccess');
            skypeAccess = $(this).find('skypeAccess');
            localAccess = $(this).find('localAccess');
            rechargeable = $(this).find('rechargeable').text();

           $('#urProductSelect').append("<option value='" + productID + "'>" + productName + "</option>");
        });
    }
}); //End ajax

    // I need to use the variable out here....
   $('#urProductSelect').change(function () {...});
```